# Wamp Error Log Watcher?

Tags: php, logging, wampserver

Like many others I use WAMP on my local machine to test my PHP code and regularly use trigger_error to pin down issues with my scripts.  This works really well but the one thing that is a constant irritant is the loquacity of the error_log file.  Every PHP Notice is accompanied by a stack trace etc.

I have often toyed with the idea of writing an application of some description that would help me to zero in on the information I want rapidly and without eye strain (I generally keep the error_log file open in my browser and just refresh it to check the latest entries).  However, that would be a digression from the real job and chances are that something of the nature already exists.  I have Googled a fair bit to find a ready made solution but have not found one yet.  Perhaps someone here might be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `tail` command in cmd.

- Download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657
- Extra info: http://www.windows-commandline.com/2010/08/tail-command-for-windows.html

Simply run `tail -f <path to *.log>` and watch your cmd when you run your script.

Now you don't have to refresh anymore.

Or did I completely misunderstand your question? :)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I was looking for something with a fancy UI that gave an audible warning each time there was a new entry in the log but tail is a good step forward till I find, or make, such a thing.

Comment: @DroidOS Programs like that do probably exist. It's just an extension on the tail command. What you can do  and what is also a great learning oppurtunity to learn commandline is to create a cronjob that checks the file every minute or so, if the last-update-date is changes accordingly to the date you saved in another file or db, it has a new error. So you can run a script that extracts all new lines from the file and sends them to your screen.